# How to pass values across Lightning Applications?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have two lightning component and two lightning application.
Comp1 is on app1 and Comp2 in on app2. Now, How can i pass the values from comp1 to comp2. Is it possible or I have to create one application instead of two ??

Comment: yes you can by using a lightning events, i would suggest go through salesforce doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm

Comment: If you can wait till winter 20, you can easily use Lightning Messaging Service.https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm?edition=&impact=

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, There are two components

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute a/>
</aura:component>
```

and

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute b/>
</aura:component>
```

and you need to pass first component's value a to second's b.

Then

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute a/>

<c:secondcomp b="{!a}">

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this but my question is -  suppose i have component1 and component2 component1 is on application1 and component2 is on application2.  In other word how to pass value from application1 to application2.